# How can I check passphrase of gpg from a file?

Tags: pipe, password, gpg

I want to check whether the passphrase of my `user-id` located inside a file is correct or not. I have stored my passphrase in a file (`/home/user/.gpg_pass.txt`), than I use it as:

```
gpg --verbose --batch --yes --pinentry-mode loopback \
    --passphrase-file=/home/user/.gpg_pass.txt
    --decrypt <file>
```

Before using this command, I want to verify that the passphrase inside the file is correctly entered. I have tried, which did not help:

`cat /home/user/.gpg_pass.txt | gpg --dry-run --passwd <key_id>`

---

From `man` of `gpg`:

```bsh
--passwd user-id
       Change the passphrase of the secret key belonging to the certificate 
       specified as user-id.  This is a shortcut for the sub-command passwd  
       of  the edit  key  menu.  When using together with the option --dry-run 
       this will not actually change the passphrase but check that the current 
       passphrase is correct.
```

---

When I enter:

```
$ gpg --dry-run --passwd <key_id>
```

Two times following window show up I enter the passphrase, (if wrong passphrase is entered it says  `Bad Passphrase (try 2 of 3)` in the GUI-console):

```bsh
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │ Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:  │
 │ "Alper <alper@gmail.com>"                                      │
 │ 3072-bit RSA key, ID 86B9E988681A51D1,                         │
 │ created 2021-12-15.                                            │
 │                                                                │
 │                                                                │
 │ Passphrase: __________________________________________________ │
 │                                                                │
 │         <OK>                                    <Cancel>       │
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Instead of manually entering passphrase into GUI inside console, can it be pipe in the `gpg --dry-run --passwd <key_id>` and can its output could be returned, verifying is the given passphrase correct or not?

---

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11381123/2402577

Comment: Did you try `gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-file=/home/user/.gpg_pass.txt --dry-run --passwd your-keyid`? As the man page also says that these are the options to allow to get the password from a file...

Comment: @dirkt Ah when the file have wrong passphrase the output is: `gpg: error changing the passphrase for keyid Bad passphrase`. If its correct, there is no output. So it was the answer i was looking for. Please feel free the convert your comment into an answer for me to accept it

Comment: Don't forget to "secure delete" your .gpg_pass.txt file after your experiment. It is very unwise to put a plaintext password in a file. It may have already been copied multiple times in your system to places you don't even know!

Comment: @elmclose What would be safest way to keep the `.gpg_pass.txt` file that has the gpg password?

Comment: At least keep it in a  password manager (lastpass, bitwarden..). If you copy and past the password you must clear your clipboard after use. Hackers love to regularly check your clipboard. Consider using a digital vault (such as veracrypt) where you can drag and drop sensitive files and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-file=/home/user/.gpg_pass.txt --dry-run --passwd your-keyid
```

as the man page also says that these are the options to allow to get the password from a file.

Note that if you want to do that from inside a script, I'd assume it sets the return code depending on the outcome, so check the return code (`$?` in most shells, use `echo $?` if you want to check manually).